# Wordpress get_next_posts loop

Tags: php, wordpress

So basicly i'm trying to loop out 3 posts and add next / prev buttons to go back and forth listing 3 new / older every time. However this is not working as expected and i'm pulling my hair trying to figure out whats wrong.

what happens is that I get a "Next" button, I can click it and it navigates me to /page/2, but the same 3 results gets shown and the button "Previous" doesnt show. Where am I going wrong? :(

```
<?php

        /*
            Template Name: News Listing
        */
    ?>
    <div id="news-list">
        <h1>Wow thats great <span>news</span></h1>
        <div class="handwritten">Uncensored and timely truth from the brewery</div>
        <div class="news-container">
            <?php
                // set up or arguments for our custom query
                $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
                $query_args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'category_name' => '',
                  'posts_per_page' => 3,
                  'paged' => $paged
                );
                // create a new instance of WP_Query
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
            ?>

            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); // run the loop ?>
            <div class="news-post">
                <?php
                    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
                ?>
                <img src="<?= $feat_image; ?>" />

                <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>

                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                <a href="#">Read more</a>
                <p class="published-date">Posted <?php the_time('d F');?></p>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <?php if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
        <div class="next-prev">
            <div class="link prev">
                <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( '<span class="handwritten">Next post</span><h4>That way</h4>' ); // display older posts link ?>

            </div>

            <div class="link next">
                <?php echo get_next_posts_link( '<span class="handwritten">Next post</span><h4>This way</h4>', $the_query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php else: ?>
        <article>
            <h1>Sorry...</h1>
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
        </article>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: And of course you have checked what value `$paged` actually contains, right?

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean? When I echo $paged; I get nothing

Comment: @CBroe Ok, you pointed me in the right direction. If the page isnt a default static home page you should use get_query_var('paged') instead of get_query_var('page')

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my template not being a standard static home page, it being a custom one.

Therefor I needed to use `get_query_var('paged')` instead of `get_query_var('page')`